# Nokia N8 Testing on actuall application

Tags: connection, symbian, nokia

I am currently developing an application using LWUIT and initial socket connection is working fine but after a while our application gets disconnected and it cant reconnect to socket? We have to shut down our application and re-open for it to reconnect.

This is happening for the Nokia N8 Symbian^3 OS. we have actuall device

Is there any SDK whereby you can test and via data cable on actual device like you do on all other OS's (BB, windows, Apple)? We have added a log into our application and it is not picking up anything significant?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt SDK lets you develop and test directly on your phone. There is a simple guide for this here:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Using_Qt_Creator_with_Symbian

This won't help you with testing your LWUIT application, however, so I'm not sure if this answers your question?